# select option for distance radius search javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i am trying to add a option drop down that can change the mile radius for example: 25 miles, 50 miles, 100miles and will update locations with in the radius selected. this is what

```
 var newOptions = {
  "Option 1": 1200,
   "Option 2": 1400,
   "Option 3": 160934
  };

  var $el = $("#selectId");
   $el.empty(); // remove old options
   $.each(newOptions, function(key,value) {
   $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
   });




    $('#selectId').change(function(){
      filterLocationsWithinSetDistance();
     });


    var withinDistanceSetting =$("#selectId option").val();; //meters


       function filterLocationsWithinSetDistance {
        if (val.distance <=  withinDistanceSetting ) { //html output 
           of customers in this range }}
```

i need it to update the output function (filterLocationsWithinSetDistance)
hopefully this makes since please let me know if you need more info. thank you

Comment: What issue are you having with all of this?

Comment: you need to set `distValue` inside the `filterLocationsWithinSetDistance()` function.

Comment: There's no need for two different variables `distValue` and `withinDistanceSetting`. They both need to be set when the user changes the dropdown. You're setting them when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value from the dropdown when the user changes it and you're doing the filtering. Your code gets it when the page loads.

And you need to get the value of the dropdown itself. `$("#selectId option").val()` returns the value of the first option, not the one the user selected.

```js
var newOptions = {
  "Option 1": 1200,
  "Option 2": 1400,
  "Option 3": 160934
};

var $el = $("#selectId");
$el.empty(); // remove old options
$.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
  $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
});

$('#selectId').change(function() {
  filterLocationsWithinSetDistance();
});

function filterLocationsWithinSetDistance() {
    var withinDistanceSetting = $("#selectId").val();
    console.log("Distance being filtered = " + withinDistanceSetting);
    var values = []; // get elements we're processing
    $.each(values, function(i, val) {
        if (val.distance <=  withinDistanceSetting ) { 
            // code that processes this element
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectId"></select>
```

Comment: so i added var withinDistanceSetting = $("#selectId").val(); into the filterlocation function but is still seems to be grabbing the first option only and after selecting another option in the drop down it does not populate with the new value. it just says there is nothing with in that radius.

Comment: I've added an executable snippet showing that it gets the correct value.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. You need to leave the original code so everyone can see what problem I fixed in my answer. If you want to show the new code you should add it as an addition, don't remove the old code.

Comment: ok yeah sorry about that. So i can see it does update the data but it does not seem to rerun the function. so it shows there is no customers within that distance

Comment: It reruns the function every time you change the dropdown.

Comment: oh dang it! typo... It works thanks for all the help!